# Creating new account for sharepoint

Tags: directory

Good day,

Guys I wish to create an user account other than an administrator which isnt associated with active directory as A.D. How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: could you say more about your environment (SharePoint version 2007/2010, foundation/server, AD users - admin/farm, etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that using local accounts is *not* recommended when working in SharePoint for a whole list of reasons.  However, it is sometimes required - especially for development farms.

If you are dealing with a single-server farm then you will need to create the new ID directly on the machine that is running SharePoint by going to Computer Management - Users and Groups and adding the user there.

Once created, you will have to add that account to the groups where it needs permissions.  That might be the local Administrators group, the Farm Administrators group in SharePoint Central Admin and possibly the Domain Administrators group for the site collection you are working with.

Comment: ok great budy, it worked, you said its not recommended? why? for security issues?

Comment: and another thing, lets say i create a local account and i wish to limit it to what it can access,example i dont wish it to see the full option of site actions

Comment: The local account is limited because it cannot access any network service, which on a multi-server farm would mean that the ID would only be recognized on the server where it was created.  No other servers in the farm would not be able to authenticate that ID.  As to limiting Site Actions, SharePoint has built-in security functions for that already.  Simply assign the user the specific permissions you wish it to have when you add the user to the site.  Better yet - create a group, add that user to the group and grant the group the specific permissions.

Comment: if you dont mind explaining , whats the up side of implementing active directory to our servers? and is it worth implementing if the total employee dont exceed 30?

Comment: The upside is that the user account would be usable on multiple servers, which becomes an issue if you have more than one server in your farm.  A domain user could hit any of the load balanced web-front-end servers and have the same permissions.  If an administrator, they could work on an App server (usually where Central Admin and other services run) as well as the web front ends.  With a machine account, they are limited to accessing only the resources available on that specific machine.

Comment: aha, ok then thx so much dave, appreciated buddy